# Element-wise multiplication of two nested lists of unequal length

Tags: python-3.x, nested-lists

I need to do an element wise multiplication of two nested lists of unequal length. I know how to do an element-wise multiplication if the length is the same but I've spent far too much time on this problem with no resolve.

I'm using Python 3.x

Each inner list of the multiplier_list is to be used individually with each inner list of the data - element wise.

```
    data = [[[2,3,4],[5,6,10],[11,12,13]],[[2,3,4],[5,6,10],[11,12,13]]]
    multiplier_list = [[2,3,4],[5,6,10]]

    expected_result = [[[4,9,16],[10,18,40],[22,36,52]],[[10,18,40],[25,36,100],[55,72,130]]]
```

Comment: if you lost "far too much time on this problem with no resolve" ... where is your code? [mre]?

Comment: Hi Patrick. Apologies for not uploading the code. I should've posted it while posting the question. Won't happen again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the data you gave, the nested lists *are* of equal length, but the factors for multiplication are at unequal levels of nesting. This can be dealt with by simply descending further into one list before actually calculating the multiplication than into the other.

For example, `multiplier_list` and `data` both have two elements. Each element of `data` is itself a list which needs to be operated on by the corresponding element of `multiplier_list`. In both cases, the lowest-level lists have three elements, which corresponds correctly.

Here's a one-liner (technically) list comprehension that produces your expected output from your given input:

```
expected_result = [
    [
        [
             (datum * factor)
             for datum, factor in zip(data_subsublist, mult_sublist)
        ] for data_subsublist in data_sublist
    ] for data_sublist, mult_sublist in zip(data, multiplier_list)
]
# [[[4, 9, 16], [10, 18, 40], [22, 36, 52]], [[10, 18, 40], [25, 36, 100], [55, 72, 130]]]
```